# Failed to start a new language worker for runtime: dotnet-isolated - latest version of C# .Net 7

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime, dotnet-isolated, azure-functions-isolated

I have an Isolated Azure Function. Now I am getting this famous error:

**Failed to start a new language worker for runtime: dotnet-isolated**

I have searched and done all possible solutions in Stack overflow and Github. The reason I am asking is most of the answers where about more than 3-4 months ago. I am wondering there would be any progress about it in latest versions? (or maybe I should downgrade to any specific version.)

It runs fine in my local but the problem appears after publishing.

I am using the latest version of .Net (.net 7) and `Function Worker 1.16.0`. All of my NuGet Packages are uptodate.
My `Azure Runtime version` is `4.22.0.20804`. And yes I have set `FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME` to `dotnet-isolated`.
In my `Program.cs` I already have added
`.ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()`

this is my project setting:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
        <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
        <RootNamespace>cg_sfsc</RootNamespace>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus" Version="7.15.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Blobs" Version="12.16.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Files.Shares" Version="12.14.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Queues" Version="12.14.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.16.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.ServiceBus" Version="5.11.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.11.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.0.13" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Storage" Version="5.1.2" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Azure" Version="1.6.3" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets" Version="7.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="7.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.3" />
        <PackageReference Include="Polly" Version="7.2.4" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <None Update="host.json">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </None>
        <None Update="local.settings.json">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
            <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
        </None>
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Any Idea what else should I do?

This is my `Progam.cs` :

```
public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
     .ConfigureAppConfiguration(config =>
     {
         config.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
             .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", false, true)
             .AddEnvironmentVariables();
     })
     .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
     {
         var configurationRoot = context.Configuration;
         services.Configure<IVSOptions>(configurationRoot.GetSection(nameof(IVSOptions)));


         services.AddSingleton<ICacheProvider, DistributedCacheProvider>();
         services.AddStackExchangeRedisCache(option =>
         {
             option.Configuration = configurationRoot.GetConnectionString("RedisCache");
         });


         services.AddHttpClient();
         services.AddLogging();

         services.AddScoped<IInventoryRepository, InventoryRepository>();

     })

    .Build();

        await host.RunAsync();

    }
}
```

and this is my `host.json` :

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "logging": {
        "applicationInsights": {
            "samplingSettings": {
                "isEnabled": true,
                "excludedTypes": "Request"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Go into your App Service > Advanced Tools > Go > Debug Console > Cmd > LogFiles > eventlog.xml. Download or edit it to view and look at the bottom and you might get more details on the real issue.

Comment: Thanks @sellotape, I didn't find anything in the log. I uploaded a summarized version here https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArqjR3UKS2pkgeMeDUhB9DSYaQGBKQ?e=56aKoH . I deleted the redundant sections. can you take a look plz?

Comment: Try "Diagnose and solve problems" in the App Service then; it can be quite good at pointing out issues causing this sort of thing.

Comment: @SharifYazdian - Could you please share your `local.settings.json` file.

Comment: Iam able to solve the issue by changing the line in `Program.cs` file.`            `.AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: false)`.Will post the answer with steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was so strange;
I was running two Azure functions in same class:
This was my **Not Working** code:

```
 public class InventorySyncFunctions
    {
        private readonly IInventorySyncService _service;
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public InventorySyncFunctions(IInventorySyncService service, ILogger<InventorySyncOnDemand> logger)
        {
            _service = service;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [Function("InventorySyncOnDemand")]
        public async Task InventorySyncOnDemand([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"InventorySyncOnDemand executed at: {DateTime.UtcNow} UTC");

            await _service.PerformInventorySyncExecute(cancellationToken);
        }

        [Function("InventorySyncTimerTrigger")]
        public async Task InventorySyncTimerTrigger([TimerTrigger("%InventorySyncCronTime%")] TimerInfo myTimer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"InventorySyncTimerTrigger executed at: {DateTime.UtcNow} UTC");

            await _service.PerformInventorySyncExecute(cancellationToken);
        }

    }
```

however, I found I have to separate the Azure Functions and call them "Run".
So Now I have two different classes:

```
public class InventorySyncOnDemand
    {
        private readonly IInventorySyncService _service;
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public InventorySyncOnDemand(IInventorySyncService service, ILogger<InventorySyncOnDemand> logger)
        {
            _service = service;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [Function("InventorySyncOnDemand")]
        public async Task Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"InventorySyncOnDemand executed at: {DateTime.UtcNow} UTC");

            await _service.PerformInventorySyncExecute(cancellationToken);
        }
    }
```

And

```
 public class InventorySyncTimerTrigger
    {
        private readonly IInventorySyncService _service;
        private readonly ILogger _logger;
    
         public InventorySyncTimerTrigger(IInventorySyncService service, ILogger<InventorySyncTimerTrigger> logger)
        {
            _service = service;
            _logger = logger;
        }
    
        [Function("InventorySyncTimerTrigger")]
        public async Task Run([TimerTrigger("%InventorySyncCronTime%")] TimerInfo myTimer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"InventorySyncTimerTrigger executed at: {DateTime.UtcNow} UTC");
    
            await _service.PerformInventorySyncExecute(cancellationToken);
        }
    }
```

it worked!

Answer (score 1):

When I have created `Azure Function .NET 7.0 Isolated`,below packages are included by default.

```cs
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.14.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.0.13" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.10.0" />
```

Initially even I got the same error when I tried to run with your `.csproj` package versions.

[image]

- Check the logs in `Azure Function App` => `Log stream` => `Filesystem Logs`

[image]

> The configuration file 'local.settings.json' was not found and is not optional. The expected physical path was 'C:\home\site\wwwroot\local.settings.json'.

There seems to be an issue with the below line of code.

```cs
.AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", false, true)
```

Change the code as below.

```cs
.AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: false)
```

- Build and Re-publish the App again.

Now, Iam able to run the deployed Azure Function without any issues.

***My `.csproj` file:***

```cs
 <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
```

***Log stream:***

[image]

***Output:***

[image]

Comment: Yes that was my mistake, that was a part of the problem, to make it "optional" but it didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Same behavior for me. The reason is explicit, dotnet 7 is not available on my linux function. Only 3.1 and 6.0 are.[image]

Thanks to Terraform, just detroy and recreate the ressources with replacing os_type = Linux by os_type = Windows on the Azure Service Plan and everything works great.

```
resource "azurerm_service_plan" "sp" {
  name                = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-sp"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  os_type             = "Windows"
  # Y1 is an as-you-go consumption plan
  sku_name            = "Y1"
}
```

Note that my code was successfully executed on my local Linux environnement, and I've changed nothing else than the os_type of the SP.